# Calling Graph Api from Web Api doesn't return all user data

Tags: asp.net-web-api, microsoft-graph-api, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity, microsoft-graph-sdks

In my ASP.NET Core Web Api, I'm trying to call Graph API to retrieve the data of other users in the organization. I'm using the On Behalf Of flow. The bootstrap token is passed in from SPA client code.

In the Startup code, I have:

```cs
builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration)
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
    .AddMicrosoftGraph("https://graph.microsoft.com/beta", "user.read user.readbasic.all profile")
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

In the Controller's Action, I have:

```cs
_graphServiceClient.Users.Request()
            .Filter($"mail eq 'someuser@myorg.com'")
            .Select((user) => new {
                DisplayName = user.DisplayName,
                City = user.City,
                Country = user.Country,
                BusinessPhones = user.BusinessPhones
            })
            .Request()
            .GetAsync();
```

However, at runtime, I only get the `DisplayName` value. I don't get the values of City, Country or BusinessPhones. They are al `null`.

When I tried the same query in Graph Explorer, I saw the values for all of them.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is there any reason why you use beta API and not 1.0 API?

Comment: Did you enable `profile` in api permissions ?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. It has to do with the bearer token. If you copy the bearer token from the graph explorer and use that in your GET you will get all user data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your code snippet has an error that you wrote 2 `.Request()`, you should remove one.

[image]

Whatever flow you used are all generating an access token so that you can access the api, therefore when you got correct data from the api, that means you have a right setting in using the flow, so I think if there's any issue, it should locate at the part of calling api. Then I did some test in my side.

Could you pls check if you call the api directly, you can get the value of `City, Country and BUsinessPhones` these 3 properties? Per my test, when I call the api, I can get response like screenshot below and by default it's null

> https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$filter=mail eq
> 'tinywang@xxx.onmicrosoft.com'&$select=mail,city,country,DisplayName,BusinessPhones,userType,usageLocation

[image]

And when I followed [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-webapp-calls-graph) to call the api via sdk, I got the same result:

[image]

My idea is checking the response of calling the api first and if we can't find the issue, then could you pls provide the tutorial you followed to help reproduce the issue.